# Openvpn on Win 10 Laptop: Can I make it show a icon clearly to know it is connected to a VPN

Tags: windows-10, laptop, vpn, openvpn, taskbar

I use OpenVPN sometimes to connect to my work network using Chrome from my Win 10 laptop.

But it is easy to forget that it is still connected to the VPN, later when using Chrome to browse. I mean the OpenVPN icon does turn Green but it's hidden on the Windows task bar at the bottom right and most of the times not even visible till I click on the up arrow down there (since there's so many icons in the taskbar right corner)

Ideally something that makes it clear in the browser that I am on a VPN e.g. How incognito mode is clear enough when ON in the Chrome browser. Or when using Express VPN on my Android cell it will display a key symbol above on the notification bar.

Any solutions for this sort of problem? e.g.

- A Open VPN setting or config file that will make it display some prominent icon when it is connected
- A windows setting so that the open vpn icon will always show on the taskbar
- A batch file or other scripting option to do this

This is how the bottom right corner looks so it is hard to tell if OpenVPN is connected to the VPN:

[image]

If I click on the up arrow at the bottom right the icon appears in Green.

[image]

Comment: Drag the OpenVPN icon from the dropdown onto the taskbar to the right of that up arrow _(e.g. on the side with the clock)_

Comment: @JW0914 Perfect! That works; if you can post that as an answer I can accept it as well!